# How to send data from ruby controller to application javascript using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have an AJAX call in my application.js which sends 3 pieces of data to my events_controller#check action:

```
//application.js
    $(document).on('click', "#check-button", function(){

        ...

        $.ajax({
                url: '/events/check',
                data: {checkList: checkList , selected_date: selectedDate , length: length },

            }
        );

    });
```

my check action:

```
#events_controller.rb
def check
    checkList = params[:checkList]
    selected_date = params[:selected_date]
    length = params[:length]

    busy_array = Array.new #this needs to be rendered in the view

    ...
    busy_array.push(user.id) #busy_array is a list of user ids from database


  end


#routes.rb
resources :events do
    get :check, on: :collection
  end
```

The view:

```
<button id="check-button" type="button">Check</button>

          <div class = "col-md-6" id="unavailable">
            <h2>Unavailable on this day:</h2>
            <ol id="unavailable-list">
              <li>THIS LIST SHOULD BE POPULATED BY BUSY_ARRAY</li>
            </ol>
      </div>
```

Now I need to send back data from `events_controller#check` to the view, but I don't know how to send `busy_array` to be rendered in `events\new.html.erb`

Thanks for you help, I am a ruby/JS beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
busy_array = Array.new #this needs to be rendered in the view
```

If that has to be available in the view, you need to define an `@instance` variable:

```
def check
    checkList = params[:checkList]
    selected_date = params[:selected_date]
    length = params[:length]

    @busy_array = Array.new
    ...
    @busy_array.push(user.id) #busy_array is a list of user ids from database
end
```

Each time you call a `controller#action`, the data/variables *within* the `action` are bound by [local scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable).

Outputting data in the `view` requires the variable to be made available across the entire instance of the class (*not* just the action/function). Thus `@busy_array`.

---

## Fix

```
#app/views/events/....
<%= button_to "Check", events_check_path %>

<div class = "col-md-6" id="unavailable">
  <h2>Unavailable on this day:</h2>
  <ol id="unavailable-list">&nbsp;</ol>
</div>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on('click', "#check-button", function(e){
  ...
  $.get('/events/check', {checkList: checkList , selected_date: selectedDate , length: length});
});

#app/controllers/events_controller.rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def check
    @busy_array = User.joins(:event).where(event: { ... }).pluck(:id) #-> return user ids where event.x = y
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js     #-> invokes app/views/events/check.js.erb
      format.html   #-> invoked when HTML request sent
    end
  end
end

#app/views/events/check.js.erb
<% @busy_array.each do |id| %>
   $("ol#unavailable-list").append("<%=j id %>")
<% end %>
```

---

> I don't know how to send `busy_array` to be rendered in `events\new.html.erb`

The variable will be available in `new` if it's an `@instance` var:

```
#app/views/events/new.html.erb
<%= @busy_array %>
```

The `view` is part of the instance of your `EventsController` class, but outside the scope of the `check` method. When you send a request to Rails, it uses an instance of the `Controller` to compile a set of HTML to return to your browser.

For example, you could sum up the `EventsController` flow as such:

```
Request > Routing > EventsController.new(request).action > Returned HTML
```

If you set `EventsController.new(request)` manually, you'd have the following:

```
@event = EventsController.new request

@event.check    #-> "busy_array" locally scoped to this function
@event.response #-> outputs view code.... @busy_array needs to be instance var
```

You'll understand better if you read up about [`MVC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

[image]

Comment: thank you, does it matter if it's not a post request and is just a get request?

Comment: Not at all, but you have to define it as such. Ajax defaults to `POST`

Answer (score 0):

For a real AJAX request in Ruby on Rails, you need to send response from check action in JS format.

**events_controller.rb**

```
def check
    checkList = params[:checkList]
    selected_date = params[:selected_date]
    length = params[:length]

    @events = Event.where("checklist = ? and date = ?, checkList, selected_date).limit(length.to_i)
    ...

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

Now, in your view, instead a check.html.erb, you will have check.js.erb. In this Javascript file, you can access to your @ variables and render partials or wherever.

**check.js.erb**

```
$("#unavailable-list").append('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "events/event", :collection => @events ) %>');
```

**_event.html.erb**

```
<li><%= event.name %></li>
```

I change busy_array for events array because I don't know what's exactly busy_array but you can change it.

This is the flow for an AJAX request.

Comment: ok, so if I did $("#unavailable-list").append('<%= escape_javascript( render @busy_array ) %>'); , it would make each entry an <li> element?

Comment: If @busy_array isn't an ActiveRecordRelation you have to specify the partial you want to render like `render :partial => "events/event", :collection => @busy_array`. Then, in your _event.html.erb you can add your <li> element.

Comment: Do you mind showing me within your answer? Sorry, I do not fully understand what you mean. How do I know if it's an Active Record Relation? I created it within my controller

Comment: ok thanks, my busy_array holds the users in the database, so if I had (instead of _event.html.erb) a _busy.html.erb, I could render :partial => "events/busy", :collection => @busy_array , and in _busy.html.erb I could write <% (&)busy_array.each do |id| %> <li><%= user.id %><li> <%end%> ?